# Is there a reason why so many sites have the same number of referrals?

Tags: support, site-statistics

I was taking a stroll through some site analytics today and something caught my eye in the [traffic sources](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources), that many (11 exactly) SE referring sites have exactly 776 visits. This seems to continue when after 776 the number drops to 388 which is exactly half of 776, however only 2 sites are shown with that number so I cannot be sure how long the trend continues.

**I find this beyond coincidence so I suspect there is something going on in the system/code/programming/what-have-you. Can it be explained?**

[image]

Comment: Well, for a start, it means those numbers are pretty much nonsense.

Comment: The numbers are sampled and not really accurate, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics) for some explanation.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Could these referrals be chat feeds?  I don't have access to the linked stats page yet.